# Yield of for...in element returns strings array

Tags: javascript, yield

I tried to print an array generated by `yield` and somehow if I use for...in statement it creates an array of strings while using regular for loop its working properly. 
Why is that happens?

```js
function *hello1(elements) {
    for(var el in  elements) yield el;
}
function *hello2(elements) {
    for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) yield elements[i];
}

var elements = [1,2,3];
console.log(elements);
console.log([...hello1(elements)]);
console.log([...hello2(elements)]);
```

Comment: Thank you all, I didn't know there is a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant to use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), not [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) which is for iterating over the enumerable keys of a target object. You can also use [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) instead of `for...of` and `yield`:

```js
function* hello1(elements) {
  for (var el of elements) yield el;
}

function* hello2(elements) {
  yield* elements;
}

var elements = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(elements);
console.log([...hello1(elements)]);
console.log([...hello2(elements)]);
```

Answer (score 2):

For getting the elements, you need to take [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

The [`for ... in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) iterates the keys (without symbols) of the object and returns strings.

```js
function* hello1(elements) {
    for (var el of elements) yield el;
}

var elements = [1, 2, 3];

console.log([...hello1(elements)]);
```

An even shorter approach returns just the array as iterable with [`yield*` expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*).

```js
function* hello1(elements) {
    yield* elements;
}

var elements = [1, 2, 3];

console.log([...hello1(elements)]);
```